# Equation of a normal line

Tags: calculus

What is the equation of a normal line to the surface $x^2+y^2+yz=3$ at the point $(1,1,1)$?

If someone could show me a quick step by step that would be amazing, thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. I see that you've asked several questions recently, but haven't indicated any work, ideas or thoughts on any of them. In order to receive appropriate help, please indicate your thoughts on the problem and what's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, in three-dimensional space a line does not have an equation. It can be specified, in many ways, by the equations of two planes that have the line in common. But more likely you want a *parametric* equation of the normal line.

For that, all you need to know one point on the line, and the direction vector. The point is easy, it is $(1,1,1)$.

For the direction vector $(a,b,c)$, you need the *gradient* of the function $x^2+y^2+yz-3$ at $(1,1,1)$.

The partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$ are $2x$, $2y+z$, and $y$. Evaluated at $(1,1,1)$ they give $(2,3,1)$. Now you have all the ingredients: the general point on the normal is $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+t(2,3,1)$.

Comment: i see thanks a lot

Comment: so it'd be like $\dfrac{x-1}{2}=\dfrac{y-1}{3}=z-1$